# Jquery validate input for no special charactors or spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to prevent users creating usernames that contain spaces and special characters.  The regex I am using prevents the special characters but isn't stopping the spaces.

```
if (/[^a-zA-Z 0-9 \S]+/.test(username)){
    alert('letters and numbers only please');
}
```

Comment: http://www.regexper.com/#%5B%5Ea-zA-Z%200-9%20%5CS%5D%2B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you have spaces in the regex. Try: `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/`